# Convert text to HPGL (plotter) vector coordinates

Tags: c++, c, text, printing, vector

I need to convert arbitrary texts into a set of vector coordinates as defined in HPGL (HP Graphics Language) to be able to print with a laser, using C/C++ if possible.

I can use any font that makes this task easier.

I've found ways to get the glyphs outlines to SVG, but I do not know how to process the SVG to get the final HPGL coordinates. And I am not sure if I need to go through SVG, it looks too complicated to get finally simple HPGL vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It is not C/C++ but I used to use a simple perl script which called [pstoedit](http://www.pstoedit.net/) (you can download its source) and then modified the result a bit to send data to a HPGL plotter.

It was basically this:

- Using inkscape I drew a picture then saved as EPS (postscript).
- I converted the resulting EPS to HPGL using pstoedit.
- Then the perl script modified the resulting HPGL a bit (mainly removing any command other than what I needed and setting the velocity)
- The result from the perl script was fed to the plotter

I had to do it this way because the HPGL from inkscape was not suitable for my plotter. If I have to do it again I would probably give [inkcut](http://inkcut.sourceforge.net/) a try. It is a plugin for inkscape and seems to generate HPGL suitable for cutters.

Since inkscape can read SVG files and then generate HPGL files, it seems you could use it.